# Error of Points in Mollweide Projection

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, geodesy, projection

I am currently working on a project using SnIa data and using Mathematica I have obtained the following points (in degrees) through the maximum likelihood process

```
point1 = {72.85 \pm 60.6242, 210.26 \pm 136.593};
point2 = {-25.17 \pm 10.23, 104.70 \pm 32.47 };
point3 = {25.17 \pm 10.22, 284.70 \pm 48.32};
point4 = {18 \pm 10, 309 \pm 23};
point5 = {-18 \pm 9, 129 \pm 23};
point6 = {-15.1 \pm 11.5, 309.4 \pm 18};
```

where \pm=$\pm$ and corresponds to the 1$\sigma$ error of the l and b. Mapping the best fit values of the data as follows:

```
GeoGraphics[{AbsolutePointSize@5, RGBColor[0.09, 0.35, 0.11], 
  Point[GeoPosition@point1], AbsolutePointSize@5, Purple, 
  Point[GeoPosition@point2], AbsolutePointSize@5, Purple, 
  Point[GeoPosition@point3], AbsolutePointSize@5, Red, 
  Point[GeoPosition@point4], AbsolutePointSize@5, Red, 
  Point[GeoPosition@point5], AbsolutePointSize@5, Blue, 
  Point[GeoPosition@point6]}, GeoRange -> {{-90, 90}, {0, 360}}, 
 GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed], 
 GeoProjection -> "Mollweide", 
 GeoGridLines -> {Automatic, {0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 
    270, 300, 330, 360}}, GeoBackground -> White, Axes -> True, 
 ImagePadding -> 25, ImageSize -> 1000, 
 Ticks -> {ticksldeg, ticksbdeg}, Background -> White, 
 AxesStyle -> Black, TicksStyle -> 15]
```

I have obtained the following picture
[image]
So I want in the final Mollweide plot that I have uploaded, to include a circle or an ellipse (different color for each point) that corresponds to the errors of l and b, however I am not sure how to do that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want a circle in the final map, or a circle on the original {l, b} space? And do you want circles or ellipses, given that the errors of l and b are different? Note that the l coordinate of point5 is missing its error.

Comment: Dear jose thank you very much for your quick response. I have edited the post accordingly, including the error of point5. I want in the final map a geometric shape (probably an ellipse) that shows the errors for each of the points that I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
point1 = {Around[72.85, 60.6242], Around[210.26, 136.593]};
point2 = {Around[-25.17, 10.23], Around[104.70, 32.47]};
point3 = {Around[25.17, 10.22], Around[284.70, 48.32]};
point4 = {Around[18, 10], Around[309, 23]};
point5 = {Around[-18, 9], Around[129, 23]};
point6 = {Around[-15.1, 11.5], Around[309.4, 18]};
```

The Mollweide projection maps 90 degrees to flat distance `Sqrt[2]`, so define this scale factor:

```
scale = Sqrt[2]/90;
```

This function will create an ellipse (of that scale) on the map at the point {l, b}, where both l, b are expected to be Around objects:

```
ellipse[{l_, b_}] := Circle[GeoPosition[{l["Value"], b["Value"]}], {b["Uncertainty"], l["Uncertainty"]} scale]
```

This is the GeoGraphics call, where I have removed axes and ticks, that you have under control:

```
GeoGraphics[{
  RGBColor[0.09, 0.35, 0.11], ellipse[point1],
  Purple, ellipse[point2],
  Purple, ellipse[point3],
  Red, ellipse[point4],
  Red, ellipse[point5], 
  Blue, ellipse[point6]
},
 GeoRange -> {{-90, 90}, {0, 360}}, 
 GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed], 
 GeoProjection -> "Mollweide",
 GeoGridLines -> Automatic, 
 GeoBackground -> None
]
```

[image]

That result corresponds to ellipses on the projected map, not ellipses on the original spheroid. Motivated by a further question from the OP, I give here an alternative way of doing this using GeoCircle, which is a geometric construction on the original spheroid. Unfortunately their is no built-in notion of geo ellipses, so I'll use geo circles whose radius is the average of the semiaxes of the ellipse. To emphasize and clarify the structure of the very large case that covers the North pole, I'll use GeoDisk instead of GeoCircle. Simply replace the definition of ellipse in the previous construction by

```
ellipse[{l_, b_}] := GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{l["Value"], b["Value"]}], Quantity[(b["Uncertainty"] + l["Uncertainty"])/2, "AngularDegrees"]]
```

Then the result is

[image]

Comment: Dear Jose thank you very much for this very nice solution. I have one more question. The ellipse of point1 lies outside the Mollweide plot. Do you know a way to make the ellipse go to -b values also?

Comment: I extended my answer to try to cover your new question, assuming I interpreted it correctly.

Comment: Dear Jose thank you very much. Indeed that was the solution I was looking for! :D